# YouTrack Attachments Storage Location

Tags: youtrack

I am reinstalling my youtrack server so i need to backup the file attachments not just the database. Where are the file attachments stored? or how to do i migrate them?. (I cannot have both servers running at the same time!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachements are stored in a database folder along with other database files, so no additional steps are necessary to migrate them. Just copy the database folder and you should be fine.